# Automatically add a section numbering to \nameref references

Tags: cross-referencing

Since `\nameref` only provides clickable links, which are obviously not printed and therefore not very helpful for anything that will eventually be printed, I need to redefine it (or use another suitable command that I'm unaware of) to achieve this.

What `\nameref` currently does:

`An important part of TDD is \nameref{sec:refactoring}.`
→ An important part of TDD is *Refactoring*.

What I would like it to do:

`An important part of TDD is \nameref{sec:refactoring}.`
→ An important part of TDD is *Refactoring **(section 1.2.3)***.

Italics indicates a hyperref link in these examples, bold is what I would like to change.
The "section" label would optimally be rendered as "chapter" for, well, chapters, and "section" for anything else. I know this is possible in some way, I've done it before, but I don't remember how (and can't look it up).

Does anyone know how to enable this functionality? It doesn't necessarily need to redefine `\nameref`, a custom command is also fine and eliminates the need for `let` or similar, so it's enough for proof of concept.

What I have so far is

```
\newcommand*{\namesectionref}[1]{\nameref{#1} (\ref{#1})}
```

However, this doesn't add a label in front of `\ref`.

Comment: a really primitive method is to define two new reference commands, one for chapter and the other for section.  the one for section would be nearly what you have now: `\newcommand*{\namesectionref}[1]{\nameref{#1} (section \ref{#1})}`.  (one could observe that the original rationale for `\nameref` was to avoid including the number in the xref.)

Comment: I have implemented something similar for arbitrary labels (such as "Mile­stone M1: Spec­i­fi­ca­tion cre­ated" or "Requirement R1"). See https://ctan.org/pkg/refenums for details.

Answer (score 4):

In many cases, you get the entity name of the reference by `\autoref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\nameautorefA}[1]{%
  \nameref{#1} (\autoref{#1})%
}
\newcommand*{\nameautorefB}[1]{%
  \hyperref[{#1}]{\nameref*{#1} (\autoref*{#1})}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Refactoring}
\label{sec:refactoring}
\verb|\nameautorefA|: \nameautorefA{sec:refactoring}\\
\verb|\nameautorefB|: \nameautorefB{sec:refactoring}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The difference between `\nameautorefA` and `\nameautorefB` is the link area.

The star forms `\nameref*` and `\autoref*` prevent links inside the link `\hyperref`.